# Cannot access wifi with Raspbian

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, wireless-adapter

I have Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 2 and I am trying to connect to WiFi with it. It is able to see current networks but when I click one it asks for password and does nothing after I click *OK* (No warning or a slightest change, I'm sure password is correct). However when I set up a personal hotspot (still with password) from my phone, it can connect to it after I click *OK*. Even then, it does not connect to internet, it just shows the signal strength bar and browser is stuck at *loading...* (I'm also sure my phone has internet and its personal hotspot works fine with other devices).

I am using **Edup 802.11n** wireless adapter. I do not have an ethernet cable since I am going to use a shared network of a dormitory where router is not in physical reach.

- How do I approach this?
- What could be the problem and a possible solution?

**Edit 1**
My question is different than [RPi sees my usb wifi dongle but doesn't see any APs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14592/rpi-sees-my-usb-wifi-dongle-but-doesnt-see-any-aps) since I am able to see WiFi but have no action when I click connect. When I try hotspots it says it is connected but there is no response from the internet when I ping. Please read my question carefully before you mark it.

**Edit 2**
`netstat -nr` gives nothing normally. and `iwconfig` says network is unassociated even right after I attempt to connect and it does not warn about any failure.

Here is the output of `netstat -nr` when I try personal hotspot

```
Destination - Gateway     - Genmask       - Flags
0.0.0.0     - 172.20.10.1 - 0.0.0.0         UG
0.0.0.0     - 172.20.10.1 - 0.0.0.0         UG
172.20.10.1 - 0.0.0.0     - 255.255.255.240 U
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RPi sees my usb wifi dongle but doesn't see any APs](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14592/rpi-sees-my-usb-wifi-dongle-but-doesnt-see-any-aps)

Comment: No it is not a possible duplicate of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14592/rpi-sees-my-usb-wifi-dongle-but-doesnt-see-any-aps.

Comment: + that question does not even have an accepted answer so even if this was duplicate it would be a necessary one.

Comment: Is the network is secured? see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md

When you say "it asks for password" do you mean a Key? Many of these kind of networks are "public", but require the user to login through a browser.

Comment: Yes it is secured in the standard way, with WEP I think. I am using it from my computer only using the password, but yes it says actually asks for "Pre Shared Key" as in the link you sent. Is that different from a password? Where should I enter the password then? (and what should I enter as a pre shared key?)

Comment: I just read about "Pre Shared Key" and it is said that it is used in a derivation of WPA. Could the problem be that raspberry pi tries to enter a WPA formatted password into a WEP network? How do I tell it to enter WEP instead?

Comment: Try doing this from the command line [as described here](http://askubuntu.com/a/16588/239729) ("part 1") and see if that provides any better clues.

Comment: Just tried but it is also ignoring my command to connect in the terminal. It is able to see networks and my network adapter (as wlan0). However when I try **sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_NAME key WEP_PASSWORD** nothing changes. No error, it just ignores the command and starts a new line. I can confirm there is no change at all by typing iwconfig. Could it be about my access permissions? I am also not able to access Libre Office, it says that I do not have sufficient access rights for it. Maybe the same reason is preventing me to change network status? Is it possible? If so what can I do?

Comment: Just logged in with root and I am able to access everything now but terminl still ignores my commands to connect

Comment: Afterward, does `iwconfig` (with no other arguments) show you connected to the ESSID?   Note that's not enough to get internet working, but it is a prerequisite.

Comment: no after I type the command to connect, then `iwconfig`, it still says "unassociated" for the access point.

Comment: Check this question to see if your adapter uses the same chip: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32005/5538 (a ralink 5370).  I think there maybe an oddball firmware issue with it on Raspbian, but it's not what bobstro is talking about.  I have a couple of them.

Comment: Its not same, mine uses Realtek RTL8188CUS, it is this one: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/EDUP_EP-N8508. It is able to receive data since I get results when I do `iwlist wlan0 s`. And since it connects to my personal hotspot (it is visible on my phone that a device is connected) hardware should also be able to transmit data. Yet it just ignores my command to connect a WIFI...